# LEFT OUTER JOIN when no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (SQL server):

1. `errorcode(code, utctime, fileversion)`
2. `errordescr(code, fileversion, description)`

`errorcode` contains the history of faults at a given utctime.

errors are mapped to a description in errordescr table.

I want to use a default fileversion value (defaultversion) if the version is not present in `errordescr` table, so I can get a default description for a given error.

-When the fileversion of an error is present in `errordescr`, but the code is not registered in `errordescr`, I want to return NULL for the description, I don't want to get the default description from 'defaultversion'.

My problem is that when I do my query, I get matches from 'defaultversion' even if there is a description in the right version.

Thanks

```
SELECT TOP 50000 sn, utctime, mydb.dbo.error.code, description FROM mydb.dbo.error 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mydb.dbo.errordescr
ON(
   (
      mydb.dbo.error.fileversion=mydb.dbo.errordescr.fileversion
      OR
      mydb.dbo.errordescr.fileversion='defaultversion'      
   )
   AND
   mydb.dbo.error.code=mydb.dbo.errordescr.code
)

ORDER BY utctime DESC
```

Exemples:
Entries in error:

```
1. code: 001, utctime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v1.0
2. code: 002, utctime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v2.0
3. code: 003, utctime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v3.0
4. code: 002, utctime: 2000-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v1.0
```

Entries in errordescr:

```
1. code: 001, fileversion: v1.0, description: "error code #1 from file v1.0"
2. code: 002, fileversion: v1.0, description: "error code #2 from file v2.0"
3. code: 003, fileversion: defaultversion, description: "error code #3 from default"
```

Results would give something like this:

Show all errors:

```
1. code: 001, utctime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v1.0, description: "error code #1 from file v1.0"

2. code: 002, utctime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v2.0, description: "error code #2 from file v2.0"

3. code: 003, utctime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v3.0, description:"error code #3 from default"

4. code: 002, utctime: 2000-01-01 00:00:00:000, fileversion: v1.0, description: NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT TOP 50000 sn, utctime, mydb.dbo.error.code, case when description is null then 'defaultversion'  else description End
FROM mydb.dbo.error 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mydb.dbo.errordescr
ON       mydb.dbo.error.fileversion=mydb.dbo.errordescr.fileversion
   AND   mydb.dbo.error.code=mydb.dbo.errordescr.code
ORDER BY utctime DESC
```

Comment: There is still a problem if I have an entry with an existing version in errordescr, but code is not, I get the description from 'defaultversion'. I would like to get NULL if version is present, but code is not. 'defaultversion' will be used only if the version value is not found in errordescr table.  Thanks

Comment: I guess I don't understand your requirement. Could you post some sample data and sample expected results?